# Add domain to Vercel app makes Next.js UI break

Tags: next.js, cloudflare, vercel

The problem is when I open my Next.js website with original Vercel domain, everything works perfectly. However, when I open with my custom domain (I'm using Cloudflare), it makes my web's styles break.

https://geoterry-web-geoterry.vercel.app/ (Working)
https://checkly.vn/ (Not working)

[image]

[image]

Solved: It is only happened on my device, and everything is fine when I clear browser caches and cookies

Comment: The websites, your links are pointing to, look identical to me. What exactly is broken on the second one?

Comment: Yeah, thy are the same to me as well.

Comment: I just added img of the differences

Comment: Btw, I just found that they are identical when I'm using another device, probably it could due to the browser or cloudflare caches